# Sqlite column id is not unique

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

below is my code i just want to display the data i inserted in the sqlite database to a text view but i have this error saying that the id is not unique.

```
    package com.example.sqlitetest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {

    TextView scrName, fName;
    Button go;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String screenName, fullName;
    Cursor cursor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDataBase", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists MyTable(ScreenName Varchar, FullName Varchar, id int(3) PRIMARY KEY);");
        db.execSQL("Insert into MyTable VALUES('joff', 'tiquez', 1);");
        cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from MyTable", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        scrName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scrName);
        fName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fName);

        while(cursor.isAfterLast() == false){
            //retrieving the data from sqlite (im not sure if im doing it right)
            String screenname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ScreenName"));
            String fullname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("FullName"));

            //this are the textview
            scrName.setText(screenname);
            fName.setText(fullname);

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        db.close();
    }
}
```

this is my whole java code. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I think this project works fine when you run it first time. When you run it second time it gives error because `id` is your `primary key` and the row with the id 1 has been already inserted to your database.

**To get rid of errors either :**

```
1) uninstall the app and run it again   
2) Don't make id as primary key   
3) Catch the exception and handle it yourself
```

Comment: i uninstall it and remove the primary key and it worked. thanks @Abhishek V :)

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest an alternative to this. What you can do is make the id column `autoincrement` as well while still keeping that column as `primary key`

**EDIT:-**
Also I have some other suggestions for you:-

`db.execSQL("Insert into MyTable VALUES('joff', 'tiquez', 1);");`

you can user [ContentValues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html) instead

`while(cursor.isAfterLast() == false){`

could be replaced with `while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){`. Looks cleaner this way.

Or you could directly replace `while(cursor.isAfterLast() == false){` with `while(cursor.moveToNext()){` and can remove out `cursor.moveToNext();` from the while block.

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: `db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists MyTable(ScreenName Varchar, FullName Varchar, id int(3) AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);");`