# error retrieving inserted data sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

Hello Stack community.

I have been developing an app which has heavy interactions with SQLite Database. I need to insert a sound as BLOB in the DB. I think i do it the right way , like this :

```
byte[] fileContent = getSoundInBytes(filesDir+item.getListItemId());
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("FileId", item.getContentFileId());
values.put("Content", fileContent);
long x = db.insert("Files", null, values);
```

The value of the "x" is acurate , it is exactly the right number in the sequence in DB.

BUT..... strangely when i try to see if the record is there , it says it is not there.  query like this:

```
public boolean isIDPresentInFiles(String fileId)
    {
         boolean isIdPresent = false;
         String query = "SELECT Count(FileId) as Count FROM Files " +
                        " where FileId = "+fileId;
         Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);


         if (c.moveToFirst())
         {
            do{
                isIdPresent = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Count"))>0;
            }while(c.moveToNext());
         }
         c.close();
         return isIdPresent;
    }
```

So "isIdPresent" returns false. Don't worry for db close because i do it separately at the end of a FOR Loop because i don't want to lock the DB by opening and closing the connection every cycle of the Loop.

What amazes me more than anything is that if I execute the query directly in DB using Mozilla sqlite manager it returns "True"(Count is greater than 0).

Pffff really exhausted with this problem. I have coded massive code for this task than i get blocked by this unknown , strange thing that doesn't want to go the right way.

EDIT : Here is a Log :

```
07-20 16:46:55.123: E/file dir(11086): /data/data/package/files/sounds/tmp/X'635B35811DF5C148A61A5651FFF79C97BB5E'/
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086): Process: package, PID: 11086
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column FileId is not unique (code 19)
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1365)
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086):    at package.db.AllEntityDBHandler.insertNewLanguage(AllEntityDBHandler.java:776)
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086):    at package.fragments.FragmentNewLanguage$3.onClick(FragmentNewLanguage.java:125)
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-20 16:46:55.183: E/AndroidRuntime(11086):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This log belongs to a method that is executed after checking if an id exists in the DB and the check returns "False" so it means that the record is not there , but strangely when the other method tries to Insert the record believing it is not present , the DB says it is there.

Comment: `fileId` is String, you need to wrap it in single quotes. Why are you using a String as an ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think this project works fine when you run it first time. When you run it second time it gives error because `FileId` is your `primary key` and the row with the id 1 has been already inserted to your database.  [From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602267/sqlite-column-id-is-not-unique)

**To get rid of errors either :**

```
1) uninstall the app and run it again   
2) Don't make FileId as primary key   
3) Catch the exception and handle it yourself
```

And you missed single quote in your query(because **fileId** is String),so use

```
String query = "SELECT Count(FileId) as Count FROM Files where FileId = '" + fileId + "'";
```

But recommended solution is to use parameterized query as

```
Cursor c = db.query("Files", new String[] { "FileId" }, "FileId" + "=?",
            new String[] { fileId }, null, null, null, null);
```

And  check **isIdPresent**  as

```
if (c!= null && c.getCount() > 0) {
    isIdPresent = true;
}
c.close();
return isIdPresent;
```

Comment: Thank you man it worked, still don't understand why it didn't want to work with my way when in DB it worked. But nonetheless its OK with the way u proposed. Now I am trying to inspect the BLOB File if it is in the DB and if I can retrieve it. Thank you.